# Why does the values set on the edittext disappear on coming back to the same fragment after going to another fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment `addtaskfragment` in which I am asking the user to provide details like name, place,etc. I have a Button in the same fragment which when clicked goes to another fragment `mycontacts` gets a string value from that fragment and is passed to `addtaskfragment`. When `mycontacts` fragment goes back to the `addtaskfragment` the values previously entered in the edittexts disappears. I want those values to stay there when the value from `mycontacts` is returned. How can I do that? My codes are as below. Please guide me step by step.

addtaskfragment.class

```
public class addtaskfragment extends Fragment {
    int mYear, mMonth, mDay;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friendspage2, container, false);
        addcontacts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Fragment fr;
                fr = new mycontacts();
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fr);

                ft.commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**mycontacts extends Fragment**

```
purple.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Fragment fr;
        fr = new addtaskfragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("CID", cid);
        Log.i("cid from long click", "" + cid);
        fr.setArguments(args);
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fr);
        ft.commit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `EditText` search text is clear it's because you're  replace `ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fr);` fragment that means it's first called `ft.remove();` and then called `ft.add();` so your `onCreateView()` method again called and create a New reference of your `EditText` so that's why your `EditText` search text is clear.

Solution is store search text in SharedPreferences on `onPause()` and load the search text value from `SharedPreferences` on `onResume()` on `Fragment`.

Implement like below:

```
private void savePreferences() {

    SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("settings",
            Context.MODE_APPEND);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    KeywordValue = inputSearch.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("onPause save keyword: " + KeywordValue);
    editor.putString("searchText","");
    editor.commit();
}
```

and

```
private void loadPreferences() {

    SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("settings",
            Context.MODE_APPEND);

    KeywordValue = settings.getString("searchText",
            "");
    inputSearch.setText(KeywordValue.toString());
    keyword_search=KeywordValue;
    System.out.println("onResume load keyword: " + KeywordValue);
    }
```

and used in your `Fragment` like

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    savePreferences();
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    loadPreferences();
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but i gues  the onresume is not getting called. can you suggest some solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `android:saveEnabled="false"` attribute in EditText. It fixed the same problem for me.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    android:saveEnabled="false" />
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59599181/6444297) you can see another example: