# Why does EditText in fragment show the same value after navigating to another fragment and back using back button in Kotlin?

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin, navigation, android-linearlayout

I'm new to Android development and Kotlin. I have bumped into this problem which confuses me.

I have 2 EditText elements in Fragment A, each with a different text. When I navigate to Fragment B and back again to A using back button, both EditText controls show the same value?! I fail to see why.

Screendumps:

[Step 1 - Fragment A with DIFFERENT values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgwwS.png)

[Step 2 - Fragment B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU7Xh.png)

[Step 3 - Fragment A now with SAME values after back navigation from Fragment B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMhSF.png)

The solution has a single activity with 2 fragments (Fragment A and Fragment B). Solution is available from Github: https://github.com/MIT-bits/singleactivity

I use NavGraph for navigation between Fragment A and B.

Fragment A is reusing a XML layout file (custom_view.xml) with a EditText. Each editText value is set in Fragment A onViewCreated method (see below)

**AFragment.kt**

```
val data = arrayOf("Text A", "Text B", "Text C")

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        view1.editText.setText(data[0])
        view2.editText.setText(data[1])
    }
```

**fragment_a.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/createWhatAboutLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include android:id="@+id/view1" layout="@layout/custom_view"></include>

        <include android:id="@+id/view2" layout="@layout/custom_view"></include>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**custom_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:background="#999"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#111"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Text" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Can someone see what I am doing wrong or missing?

Any input is valuable...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add attribute `android:saveEnabled="false"` in EditText

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:background="#999"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#111"
    android:typeface="normal"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:saveEnabled="false"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="Text" />
```

Comment: Here comes the savior!!
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Cause:

Because two include of EditText have same id,so the fragment cache the same value

Solution:
  Let EditText get a different id

```
val parent = view1.editText.parent as ConstraintLayout
view1.editText.id = parent.id + view1.editText.id
```